# How to get length of text box from webpage in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html

How can I get text from text box, search box from webpage. I am trying to get text and and get length to check if it's empty.
e.g.

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
```

I tried `driver.find_element_by_name('p').text` But it prints out null even though text is there.

Comment: More information please. I can't tell if you're writing in Python or JS since you have both tags.

Comment: i am writing in python..edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `input` web element use `el.get_attribute('value')`:

```
In [14]: driver = webdriver.Chrome()

In [15]: driver.get('http://www.yahoo.com')

In [16]: search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[title=Search]')

In [17]: search.get_attribute('value')
Out[17]: u''

In [18]: search.send_keys('SO the best!')

In [19]: search.get_attribute('value')
Out[19]: u'SO the best!'
```